# Should I contact a potential PhD supervisor who strongly encouraged me to apply after not having heard from my application?

Tags: phd, application, interview, international-students

I have applied to an interdisciplinary program in a very top US university. My undergrad is in one of the fields involved. Back in November, I contacted a potential PhD supervisor (sending him my CV). We had a chat over Zoom, and he told me that I "will get offers". He told me has spoken about me to a Prof at my current institution who knows me, and based on my background, we started discussion potential projects and co-supervisors. He encouraged me to chat with one of his current grad students, whose undergrad is on the same field as mine. When I chatted with the PhD student, he was really trying to "sell" me the university. He told me that it was very likely that I will get invited for an interview and get offers. It's now February and:

- I haven't heard anything from the program
- In gradcafe, at least 2 students mentioned that they were invited for interviews in December
- I asked the PhD student if he knows anything, he said he doesn't.

Should I contact the potential supervisor, in case my application was overlooked and he can still do something? (He is **not** on the main committee of the program, though.) On the other hand, I am afraid of looking impatient or unpolite, and ruining my remaining chances of getting in.

(**Note**: I am an international student, studying outside the US. Is there any chance that international applications are processed later, or don't get interviews because of timezones?)

Comment: Do you have offers from other universities and are waiting to hear from this one before making a decision? It seems like you have nothing to lose by asking them. You can just send a short, polite email asking if there are any updates on your application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am waiting to hear back from all of the other institutions too

Comment: In some cases, the department might consider your conversation with the faculty member your “interview” if there were no red flags with your application. In my program, there were generally a couple of applicants who were so strong they skipped the interview phase each year.

Answer (score 2):

From my experiences in an engineering program at a public university, I've heard that domestic applicants are processed first. I don't think it would hurt to follow up with the potential supervisor. I agree with astronat above about sending a  polite email to follow up with the potential Ph.D. supervisor. You could also ask this professor when you can expect to hear back from the university.